# SDL2, how predict rect coordinates after rotation?

Tags: geometry, rotation

My goal - move sprite, left and right arrows keys must set directions of moving.I struggle with rotation geometry few days, and it beat me.
My code below

```
void rotate_point(float cx, float cy, float angle, int *px,int *py) {
    *px = cos(angle) * (*px - cx) - sin(angle) * (*py - cy) + cx;
    *py = sin(angle) * (*px - cx) + cos(angle) * (*py - cy) + cy;
}
```

> https://pastebin.com/vUvnNkKb

How you can see, moves of red line on rotations mismatched with X,Y of sprite rect.Many thanks to everyone who can helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in the second line you are using **px** that has been changed in the first line.

Remember old value and use it for correct rotation like this:

```
void rotate_point(float cx, float cy, float angle, int *px,int *py) {
    float tmp = *px;
    *px = cos(angle) * (tmp - cx) - sin(angle) * (*py - cy) + cx;
    *py = sin(angle) * (tmp - cx) + cos(angle) * (*py - cy) + cy;
}
```

Comment: @az0009990 Did this clue solve your problem?

Comment: yeap solve, its my attention fault. Thank you !